# How much light does a scented oak fern need?

Tags: houseplants, light, ferns

Now I have been reading that ferns don't need a lot of light — so I got one. However, what I can't seem to find is just how much is meant by *not a lot*.

I plan on keeping the fern in a room with one big north facing window. The room never gets direct sunlight as there is a balcony above the window. The only place for the fern is in the back corner of the room. This means that it will be getting minimal light.

The fern in question is a *scented oak fern* (gymnocarpium robertianum).

Just how much light does it need to survive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a misconception about ferns as houseplants, which is that they like very low light conditions. Unfortunately, most don't - in their natural habitat outdoors, they may grow in shadier spots, or places where they receive dappled sunlight, but will be receiving much more light outside than they do indoors in such a situation as you describe. The fern you've bought, along with most others, will do better on the windowsill, or directly in front of a north or east facing window, but not near any heat source. Temperature indoors is also important - they prefer cool but not cold nights, and a temperature range between 60-70 deg F, and like high humidity. So far as I can ascertain, this particular fern isn't one usually kept indoors as a houseplant.

If you want a plant for such a relatively dark situation indoors, an Aspidistra would be a better choice.